# Controller gains behind Joint::SetVelocity?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

In a plugin I am setting the rotational speed of a joint by using **Joint::SetVelocity**.  The maximum force on that joint is limited by SetMaxForce.

I couldn't find the implementation of SetVelocity in Joint.cc. How does SetVelocity set the speed exacty? Is there a PID control in the background? If so how can I change the PID gains?
I am using ROS Hydro and Gazebo 1.9.

BR

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7806/controller-gains-behind-joint::setvelocity?/) by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/545/eisenhorn/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 43 on 2015-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

`SetVelocity` is implemented differently for different physics engines. Gazebo is compatible with several core physics engines: ODE, Simbody, Bullet, and DART. However, only ODE and Bullet are available in 1.9, and in all versions ODE is the default. `Joint` is actually an abstract class, and there's a different implementation for the different physics engines. There are also different implementations for the different kinds of joints (hinge, prismatic, etc.). To find the implementation of `SetVelocity`, look in folder `gazebo/physics/ode/` for `ODEJoint` and `ODEHingeJoint` (since it sounds like you are using a rotating hinge joint).

As you can see if you read the source code, there is no PID control in the background for `SetVelocity`. There is a [PID class](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/1.9.1/classgazebo_1_1common_1_1PID.html) that computes PID math for you, which you could try using for PID velocity control.

---

Originally posted by [jackie](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1042/jackie/) with karma: 31 on 2015-01-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/545/eisenhorn/) on 2015-01-16**:
Sorry for my late answer. Yes it’s a HingeJoint. I am using ODE. The reason I ask is the very odd system response (aquired by getvelocity) which turns out to be a ramp function. The system is a 4 wheel robot. The velocity for 2 hingejoints connected to wheels is set. SetVelocity uses the tSetParam(dParamVel, _angle); (at least in gazebo 1.9) function. Shouldn't this set the velocity instantaneous?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Jackie's answer is good, but I'll add a bit more here. The behavior of `SetVelocity` has been different for each physics engine up through gazebo4. For example, `ODEJoint::SetVelocity` uses a velocity controller with a `max_force` parameter (see [ode user guide](http://www.ode.org/ode-latest-userguide.html#sec_7_5_0), specifically `dParamVel` and `dParamFMax`). On the other hand, [BulletJoint::SetVelocity](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/gazebo_4.1/gazebo/physics/bullet/BulletHingeJoint.cc?at=default#cl-216) sets the velocity of the child link relative to the parent.

With gazebo5 (implemented in [pull request 1218](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/1218/change-behavior-of-odejoint-setvelocity/diff)), `ODEJoint::SetVelocity` will match the behavior of bullet and other physics engines by setting the child velocity relative to the parent. This will also allow the `dParamVel` and `dParamFMax` parameters to be used for Coulomb joint friction.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2015-01-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1